# How to import wpf view inside a viewmodel using MEF and Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I wanted a WPF application with tray icon when minimized.

I used [wpf NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon),
I am using MEF with Prism

my bootstrapper looks like:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper{

        protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell() { 
            return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>(); 
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell(){
            base.InitializeShell();    
            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();               
        }

        protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog(){
            base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
            AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Shell).Assembly));
        }
}
```

I named my Mainwindow as Shell and added `[Export]` attribute.
In my `NotifyIconViewModel` for show command I used

```
public ICommand ShowWindowCommand{
            get{
                return new DelegateCommand{
                    CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow == null,
                    CommandAction = () =>
                    {
                        Application.Current.MainWindow = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
                        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                    }
                };
            }
}
```

But it shows

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code 
>   is thrown when I try to get the instance of Shell

I am pretty new to MEF, Prism. Can I get some help ?

update:
When the close button is clicked the following event is triggered which closes the MainWindow.

```
public ICommand HideWindowCommand{
            get{
                return new DelegateCommand{
                    CommandAction = () => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(),
                    CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow != null
                };
            }
}
```

Comment: You have assigned the `Application.Current.MainWindow` property in the bootstrapper's `InitializeShell()` method. Why do you want to assign it again in the `ICommand` implementation?

Comment: that is because when I close the following code will close it `public ICommand HideWindowCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand { CommandAction = () => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(), CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow != null }; } }`